# VBA Excel AutoShapeType not retained after copy

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

For a project I need to copy boxes (shapes of type msoShapeCube) from one sheet to another, multiple times. To place them properly one next to the other, the "ratio" of the cube is to be retrieved (Adjustments.Item(1)).
but after being pasted, the AutoShapeType of the msoShapeCube is turned to "msoShapeMixed" (which has no Adjusmtents). How do I keep the original ShapeType, or alternatively, how do I retrieve the ratio of the cube?
(as a work around, I could use the Adjustments.Item(1) of the original shape, but I would really like to understand why the shape style is modified).

code snippet :

```
    Dim thisBox As Shape
    Dim refBox As Shape
 
    boxLength = Feuil23.Range("E33").Value
    boxWidth = Feuil23.Range("E34").Value
    boxHeight = Feuil23.Range("E35").Value
    nbBoxInLength = Feuil23.Range("I33").Value
    nbBoxInWidth = Feuil23.Range("I34").Value
    nbLayers = Feuil23.Range("I35").Value

    nomCarton = boxLength & "x" & boxWidth & "x" & boxHeight
    Count = 1

    'FindCarton is a sub returning the Shape index of my box, if found, or -1 if not found.
    If (FindCarton(nomCarton) <> -1) Then
        Set refBox = Feuil13.Shapes(nomCarton)
        ' I checked the AutoShapeStyle of refBox ; it is =14 (msoShapeCube)
        ' a spy on refBox clearly states "msoShapeCube" for this variable.
        ' Loop to stack layers
        For iInLayers = 1 To nbLayers
            ' Loop to add boxes in horizontal direction
            For iInLength = 1 To nbBoxInLength
                ' Loop to add boxes in opposite direction
                For iInWidth = 1 To nbBoxInWidth
                    refBox.Copy
                    Feuil23.Range("E11").Select
                    Feuil23.Paste
                    Feuil23.Shapes(nomCarton).Name = nomCarton & "_" & Count
                    Set thisBox = Feuil23.Shapes(nomCarton & "_" & Count)
                    ' a spy on thisBox says "msoShapeMixed" for this variable.
                    ' I do not understand why...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a spy"? You can simple use `Debug.print refBox.AutoShapeType` and then `Debug.print thisBox.AutoShapeType`. Don't both of them return 14 in `Immediate Window`, as it should? If not, I am afraid that using `Feuil23.Shapes(nomCarton).Name = nomCarton & "_" & Count` you may set a different shape than the one you need. Sometimes, Excel changes the copied shape name. For instance, from copied "Cube 1" in pasted "Cube 2". That's why I would suggest to identify the pasted shape using `Set thisBox = Feuil23.Shapes(Feuil23.Shapes.count)`. The last born/pasted one...

Comment: In order to make your code faster and be sure that you created that specific autoShape type, you can avoid using clipboard (at least, for testing purpose) trying the next way: `Set refBox = Feuil13.Shapes(nomCarton)` then `Set refBox = Feuil23.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeCube, refBox.left + refBox.width, refBox.top, refBox.width, shS.height)`. It will now become the reference and you can add as many shapes you need, shoulder to shoulder. Of course, you can manipulate the positioning as you wish. This is only an example. Of course, you could set a different name for firstly added one...

Comment: Activating, selecting, using clipboard consumes Excel resources and shows down the code...

Comment: Do you really need help?

Comment: Hi FaneDuru,
sorry, yesterday was a busy messy day...
"spy" is most probably called something else on English version (watcher? watchdog? lower part of VBA window where I can add expressions/variables to watch their values)
on Sheet23/Feuil23, the shapes have their right names and I can identify them individually. There are many other shapes in the same sheet and I am a bit reluctant at giving a "random" name (a number I do not know because it depends on how many shapes there was before).

Comment: I note down your suggestion to speed up the copy and will check if it has any effect on AutoShapeStyle of the pasted shapes. they still all are cubes for sure, looking at them in the sheet.
Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Starting from FaneDuru's answer, creating the shape each time does the trick: new shape obvsiouly is an msoShapeCube.

```Set refBox = Feuil13.Shapes(nomCarton) \ Set thisBox = Feuil23.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeCube, refBox.left + refBox.width, refBox.top, refBox.width, refBox.height)```
Then I did some cosmectics to change text, Fill and Line colors, to reflect the original shape, and moved the cube to the next.

Comment: But it would also be good to clarify the issue you asked for, I think...  I tried your way (only for testing reasons) and I could not reproduce the issue. Did you try testing in the way I suggested? Firstly using `Debug.Print` for both shapes to return `AutoShapeType `...

Comment: well... it is 14 (msoShapeCube) from start to end. I do not understand. I copy-pasted my original question in a function called DEBUG, added the debug.print instructions, and AutoShapeStyle is 14 for both shapes.
but for SURE it was "2" the other day. I do not see where the difference is in the code.

Comment: You can also check the older shapes (the one copied yesterday) but I am pretty sure that all of them will be of type `msoShapeCube`. The object **type** may be different according to the way of evaluation. For instance an `ActiveX` sheet object is also a shape and having properties form both types side. It depends on what kind of object did `Watch Window`  its evaluation, I think... You can also try `Debug.Print TypeName(refBox)` or `Debug.Print refBox.Type`...

Comment: ```TypeName = Shape```
```type = 1```
mystery remains unsolved.
thanks for your tips and time!

Comment: NO! It just proved my above suppositions... It shows the type of the object! It does not show its `AutoShapeType`. It evaluates the object as a shape (which it is, in fact...).